# redirect with web.config exclude robots.txt

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config

I tried to do like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/robots\.txt$" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But it didn't work... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be great if you can provide proper description to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your rule is correct, most probably your browser cached 301 redirects. Can you please clear browser's cache and try to access `robots.txt`